# Is there a way to call the export function of outlook via c#?

Tags: c#, outlook

If you are opening up your Outlook Client and go to "File-> Import and Export -> Import and Export" you will be able to export Outlook contacts to a plain text format in .csv file.

Because Microsoft published a library to access Outlook via C#, I wanted to ask if there is some way to access this function via C#, aswell. I didn't find anything in the API.

If not do you have a idea how to create the plain text by yourself?

I am using Outlook and 2016 and so the 2016 library.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate Outlook from C# and export your contacts programmatically. For example, see [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) to get started quickly.

Basically you need to get the contacts folder or find each folder with the [DefaultItemType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865360.aspx) property which returns a constant from the [OlItemType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869291.aspx) enumeration indicating the default Outlook item type contained in the folder.

The [GetDefaultFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866724.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Namespace class eturns a [Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863890.aspx) object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile.

Iterating through contact items in Outlook you can create a .csv file. For that you may consider automating Excel, the [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) method of the Workbook class allows to saves changes to the workbook in various file formats inclusing CSV. The FileFormat parameter can be one of the [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) enumeration.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I can solve my problem now. :) - Just one more question: Do you also know a way how to get another contacts folder than the default folder?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model exposes ContactItem.SaveAs method, which allows to export a given contact in a few formats (VCard, MSG, TXT, etc.). It will not let you export multiple contacts to a CSV file.

Comment: Exporting multiple contacts to multiple files would be okay aswell. I just need an automated process.

Comment: Call ContactItem.SaveAs.